# Login to external website on click of button

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a button using jquery POST method. When the button is clicked I m trying to send the login credentials to server and log me in to this website: https://kintai.jinjer.biz/sign_in

However I am not getting any response from server.
Any ideas woud be highly appreciated
My code is :

```
<head>
<title> Approach to Login</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("https://kintai.jinjer.biz/sign_in",{

    company_code:"1234"
    email:"1234"
    password:"d5817096"
    },function(response){
    alert("success");
    });

    });

});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<button> Login </button>




</body>
```

Comment: The missing comma `,` in all ends params of  `$.post`... `company_code:"1234",
    email:"1234"`

Comment: Have you tried opening your browser's console and looking for errors?

Comment: yes. There are  0 errors however I still don't get  "success" response.

Comment: @Roy Bogado and it still doesn't work after putting in commas ,

Comment: @Programmingnoob It's working with **commas**, just try https://jsfiddle.net/0d5vLgtc/

Comment: @RoyBogado Thank you for the suggestion. I wonder why I am not getting a response in google chrome though. Can you suggest me how to redirect into logged in page after getting response? much appreciated

Comment: instead of `alert("success"); ` you can use `console.log(response)` and you can see what's the response (a 404 not found!). If you want a redirect, just use [window.location.href="url"](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Comment: what does a 404 error mean? is something wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the URL of your API from `https://kintai.jinjer.biz/sign_in` to `https://kintai.jinjer.biz/v1/sign_in`. This is the URL where API is routing. The link you were trying to navigate is the url to only show login page and there is different URL for login post request with `v1` in it

You can also find out API request details by routing to login URL `https://kintai.jinjer.biz/sign_in` and use the network section

```
        $.post("https://kintai.jinjer.biz/v1/sign_in", {

            company_code: "1234",
            email: "1234",
            password: "d5817096"
        }, function (response) {
            alert(response);
        });
```

**API Response**

```
{"code":500,"message":"入力項目に誤りがあります","data":{}}
```

Comment: Print out your response in alert or use console.log

Comment: what do you mean by appending V1?

Comment: how did you get the api response?

Comment: ```https://kintai.jinjer.biz/v1/sign_in``` use the followin url. This is the url where API is routing. Kindly let me know if this answer is helpful to you

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please tell me how you got the API response? When i press button, i am not getting any response even when I inspect element

Comment: Because I change your URL from ```https://kintai.jinjer.biz/sign_in``` to ```https://kintai.jinjer.biz/v1/sign_in```. I run your link ```https://kintai.jinjer.biz/sign_in``` on browser and put credentials on it and then I look out the API request details from network section

Comment: Also If you find out my answer useful. Marked it as accepted answer and vote for it

Comment: thank you for your response. No i cant seem to make the post request work. however when i do it using html form the post request is successful it works. Any idea why its not working using Jquery?

Comment: Its working also with the jQuery on my end as I also have shown you the response. Have you replaced this url ```https://kintai.jinjer.biz/v1/sign_in``` with the old one

Comment: thank you for your response. The code you suggested does work. when i print out response using console.log it says login successful. However when i redirect to https://kintai.jinjer.biz/staffs/top using window.location.href,  I am not logged in. On the contrary, when I use submit using only html form, i get redirected to https://kintai.jinjer.biz/v1/sign_in with the same message that i get in console. and when i go to the url   https://kintai.jinjer.biz/staffs/top, I am logged in.  how come it work with html form submit but doesn't work with ajax? I want to login without opening V1 page

Comment: That's been an another issue.You can create a separate thread for that.